# SQL Hierarchy unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a hierarchy of components, fx.:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS(id, name, price, component_type)

CREATE TABLE SUB_COMPONENTS_1(...)

CREATE TABLE SUB_COMPONENTS_2(...)
```

Where the SUB_COMPONENTS tables is using the supertype's id column as foreign key, and they get 'populated' depending on what component_type it is. (i.e. the component_type column)

I've been trying to follow:
http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/808389-design-question-type-heirarchy-supertype-queries
But can't get my head around how he can make "vehicle_type" UNIQUE, and be able to create multiple entries in the vehicle table with the same "vehicle_type" ?

Any help understanding this, would be much appreciated!

Updated:

Relational schema's without relationships is about as far as I've come:

Components(component_id: serial, name: string, type: string, price: double)

Wheels(wheel_id=component_id, kind: string, price=component_price)

Motor(motor_id=component_id, kind: string, price=component_price)

Cars(name: string, total_price, wheels=component_id, motor=component_id....)

Comment: What's the schema for SUB_COMPONENTS_1 and SUB_COMPONENTS_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about understanding what is going on in the link you posted, the example is not saying that `vehicle_type` is unique, it's saying that a **combination** of `vin` and `vehicle_type` is unique. The example is using the combination of these two columns as a key. However, I would recommend using explicit id's as keys (e.g. `ComponentID` would be the primary key on the `Components` table and the foreign key on each of the subcomponent tables.)  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Components
(
    ComponentID int identity(1,1) not null,
    // Other columns here
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ComponentID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ComponentID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
)

CREATE TABLE SubComponents1
(
    SubComponent1ID int identity(1,1) not null,
    ComponentID int not null,
    // Other columns here
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SubComponent1ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SubComponent1ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
)

GO

ALTER TABLE SubComponents1  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SubComponents1_Components] FOREIGN KEY(ComponentID)
REFERENCES Components (ComponentID)
GO

ALTER TABLE SubComponents1 CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SubComponents1_Components]
GO
```

I will ammend this answer to include more details pertaining to your problem if you can better explain what, specifically, your issue is (along with schemas of your child tables).

Comment: Just what I needed to 'fiddle' on with my project!
You've posted what seem to me as some advanced, but very useable code, only problem is that I'm a beginner, and only understand the basics of SQL. Would love too see the above written, as simple as possible! 
Perhaps I might add that I'm doing this in postgressql - if this makes any difference?
Haven't learned about 'identity', was going to use the serial data type, any difference?
Nor have I learned about 'CLUSTERED', 'ASC' and only got the basics on 'CHECK'
Updated original post

Comment: This is SQL server code - the tag on your post indicated that you are using SQL server. `ASC` stands for ascending, it's just for ordering. `CLUSTERED` is related to indexes and you can omit it if you'd like. Even if you are not using SQL server, the concept remains the same - make the foreign key on your `Subcomponents` point to the primary key of your `Components`. The primary key identifies the row in the current table and the foreign key identifies a relationship to a row in another table. Each of your tables should have a primary key.

Comment: The tables that have a "parent" (i.e. component is a parent for each subcomponent table) should have a foreign key referencing the parent table.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you just need two tables

CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS(id, component_type) 
    CREATE TABLE SUB_COMPONENTS(s_id, name, Price)

ID   Component_Type 
  1   MIG 
  2   SU

```
SUB_COMPONENT contains s_id as foreign key So the table values will be
```

1   MIG   $30 
   1   MIG-15   $20 
   1   MIG-17   $30 
   2   SU-25    $30 
   2   SU-25    $20

You can include as many subtypes you need in the sub_Components table with price.
You can get the results with this query 
SELECT * FROM SUB_COMPONENTS where s_id = 1 ( FOR MIG Type Or 2 for SU Type ) 
OR join the tables and order by name You get the list in hierarchy.

According to my understanding I hope this will answer your question.